# Double sum involving binomial coefficients and a fraction

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

In the course of my work in Quantum Field theory, I have encountered the following sum
$$
S(m,n)=\sum_{i=1}^m {m \choose i} {m\choose i-1} \sum_{j=1}^n {n\choose j}{n\choose j-1}\frac{1}{i+j}
$$
where $m,n$ are positive integers. It is easy to write one of the sums as a hypergeometric function
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n {n\choose j}{n\choose j-1}\frac{1}{i+j}=\frac{n}{i+1} F(i+1,1-n,-n ; 2, i+2 ; 1)
$$
but I haven't been able to write a closed expression for the double sum $S(m,n)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you need a closed expression on that?

Comment: There is no profound reason to expect it / need it. This sum is just one in four terms in a long computation; all the others are given by superficially similar sums, that admit closed expressions.